# What hash function should I use for password?

Tags: laravel

Laravel's default UserFactory class contains following definition method:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
```

The password key contains hashed password string value. In case I want to use another password value, what hashing function should I use to hash it like this:

```
'password' => HashFunctionName('mynewpassword');
```

? For context: I use Auth:attempt function for authentication:

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request){
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return response('you are logged in');
        }
        return response('Credentials are not valid', 401);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Bcrypt will be used as the hashing algorithm:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#introduction

The code uses `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($somePassword);` which will create a Bcrypt hash for your given password, according to the settings you have defined in `config/hashing.php`.